# Inifinite loop when using Meteor.call inside helper

Tags: javascript, methods, meteor, meteor-helper

I spent so much time on my meteor app, and now that users are coming in, it's so slow! Almost unusable, specially on mobile.

I am having to revamp all my code and try to pass all logic to the server so the client is not so overloaded.

However, I am running into many issues. I've tried all sort of solutions but nothing is working.

Anyways, here is the issue at hand. When I try to use server side methods, an infinite loop gets triggered that will console.log on the server thousands of times.

Here is the code

on templates/question.js

```
Template.questionItem.helpers({
      editPermission: function(){
        var question = this
        Meteor.call('checkForEditPermission', question, function(error, result){
          console.log(result)
          Session.set('editPermissionVar', result)
        });
        return Session.get('editPermissionVar')
      }
  });
```

on server/question.js

```
  if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    Meteor.methods({
      checkForEditPermission: function(question) {
        if (Meteor.user() && (question.user_id == Meteor.userId())) {
          return true
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

This is a very simple helper. I have dozens of other, more complex helpers, but I can't figure out how to put them server side. I was taught to do things on the client, never realizing I was overloading it.

Not sure if this helps, but what I had before (the client only helper) is much simpler:

```
editPermission: function(){
    if (currentUser && (this.user_id == currentUser._id)) {
      return true
    }
  }
```

Doesn't need meteor.call.

The question is, how do you deal with calling methods from client and using them as helpers. I have tried many things, like reactive vars and session variables, but nothing seems to work. I know this particular example is very simple, and wouldn't take much computation, but I think the principle is the same with more complex helpers. The question is how to move them to the server.

Thanks

Comment: You are causing an infinite loop because the method re-runs every time it gets a result. You can try my package to avoid the issue in this particular case: https://atmospherejs.com/simple/reactive-method

Comment: thanks! I'm testing implementation this and seems to be doing the job pretty well. What happens in future updates? Will this someday stop working? I would be relying on this pretty heavily so I'm not sure if this is a bad idea.

Comment: A slow Meteor app on the client usually points to an error in the client code (such as the infinite loop mentioned by @stubailo) or an overloaded server. Try profiling the client code with your FF or Chrome js profiler to see where all the time is spent. Your efforts moving code to the server are likely not only to be wasted, but to give you server-side scalability problems. Part of the premise of Meteor (and Node) is to move logic to the clients since then you're adding compute capacity with every client.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is, how do you deal with calling methods

How I deal is Meteor.call wich makes changes in database and just displaying data with cursors.

So for example as you have some template like:

```
Template.exammple.events({'click .sth' : function(event){
    Meteor.call("serveside", {some: data});
    return false;
});
```

In 'serverside' I got all callculations or DB queries/inserts/updates etc

and helper:

```
Template.example.helpers({
    example : function(){
    return dbCollectionName.find();
    });
```

In this way I do not need to use Meteor.call for pulling data/results. Mostly I save results in its raw shape and just addjusting diplaying after pulling them from with cursor.
MongoDB works perfect with meteor, and if you need some aggregation you can use this extension: [Meteor Aggregate](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am doing some studying on cursors to understand how your solution would work. The part that I am still struggling to understand is where do you declare your varilable (in your example) dbCollectionName so you can manipulate it with the cursor? I am trying to use the Meteor.users collection so I can't simply declare a new collection for example. Could to tell me how to get this variable so it's global to all helpers and events? Do I just redeclare the collection? I'm sure it's super simple and I'm just missing it but would really appreciate it.